# Working with the DbContext in a non-extended class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting the following exception when running the code bellow:

**The entity type DomainUser is not part of the model for the current context.**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbContext = new DbContext(@"Data Source=...\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=True");
            var entities = dbContext.Set<DomainUser>().ToList();
        }
    }

    [Table("DomainUsers")]
    public class DomainUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE1**

It works fine if I do specify the query, so what I'm a missing so that EF generates the query itself. I'm coming from an HNibernate+Fluent background.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new DbContext(@"Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=True"))
        {

                var entities = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DomainUser>("select * from DomainUsers;").ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    [Table("DomainUsers")]
    public class DomainUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I got it working with the code bellow, which I had already tested, the thing is, the SomeContext class does not provide any information that I can't provide when I'm using the generic DbContext directly and creating another dummy class just to have some dull properties is really a strange thing to me. They do a lot of type checking anyway, so why not have just one context and if the type used in the Set method is not contained in the context, just do some reflection and add it. I still find it strange that I really need to define a context all the time, let's see what other say

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new SomeContext(@"Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

                var entities = dbContext.Set<DomainUser>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    [Table("DomainUsers")]
    public class DomainUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeContext : DbContext
    {
        public SomeContext(string conn) : base(conn) { }


        public DbSet<DomainUser> DomainUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

Any ideas of what is going on.

Comment: just my 2 cents but, how can EF know that `DomainUser` is a part of the DB? when you create a new class and extend `DbContext` you define there both the connection string and the list of `DbSet` which are part of that model.
In your code it doesn't show that `DomainUser` is a part of dbContext.

Comment: All I'm doing is mapping a CLR type to a database table, EF does not need to know about that type, unless I'm wrong. See update:

Comment: Try to add this `var set = context.Set<DomainUser>();` in the first line of main (in your original post).
let me know if that worked for you. **EDIT** - add it after the first line in the main -> and try to run `set.ToList()`

Comment: @LiranBo this:                 var set = dbContext.Set<DomainUser>();
                var entities = set.ToList();

Comment: hmm ya, did it work?

Comment: @LiranBo why would the result of: var set = dbContext.Set<DomainUser>(); var entities = set.ToList(); be different from: dbContext.Set<DomainUser>().ToList()? of course the result is the same :P

Comment: oh lol.. didn't notice the syntax.. just found this on msdn and thought it could help.. anyway ya:)

Comment: @LiranBo thanks for your help anyway. If I really need to create the context the typical way I will do it so, actually I will go with that approach and see if I can't find a way to get this working without having to explicitly create a context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a property to the DbContext

```
public DbSet<DomainUser> DomainUsers { get; set; }
```

Once you have done that you should be able to do

```
dbContext.DomainUsers.ToList();
```

## Update

I'd say it's always best practice to extend the context as follow

```
public class FunkyContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<DomainUser> DomainUsers { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: how will he do it without extending the dbContext class?

Comment: What if I don't have a DomainUser context, which is happening in this case? Do I always need to create a class that extends DbContext?

Comment: There must be a way do achieve that without extending the DbContext, I recall seeing that a few years ago.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't want to extend it? I've updated the answer

Comment: @Heberda I don't see why I should. It might be a best practice, but I it is kind of dull in my case, because I will create repository classes around the contexts anyway and the returned entities.

Comment: what happens if you change `var entities = dbContext.Set<DomainUser>().ToList();` to `dbContext.Set<DomainUser>();`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm pretty sure I can call ToList or any of the Linq extension methods on a DbSet since it is a IQueryable type, what I'm missing is something else.

Comment: I appreciate that but don't you need to add it to the set first? Then you can call ToList()

Comment: @Heberda maybe I'm expecting way too much from EF but what I was hoping would be for the EF to generate a select statement without me having to do it with the SqlQuery. If I create a DomainUserContext, I wont specify how to retrieve the day the EF does it, so the fact that I need to create a class with just some mapping is annoying.

Comment: I can see where your coming from, sometimes using 3rd party software means using 3rd party software. One extra class might be annoying but it also solves your issue.